# How to pass null for datetime in query string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, postman

I'm trying to execute an API that send DateTime? parameter as query string. Below is my API:

```
[HttpGet("filter")]
public async Task<ActionResult<PagedList<Inv>>> GetFilterAsync([FromQuery] DateTime? dateFrom, [FromQuery] DateTime? dateTo, [FromQuery] int page, [FromQuery] int pageSize)
    {
```

But when I try to execute it in postman as below, I'm getting an error.

```
http://localhost:5000/api/Inv/filter?dateFrom=null&dateTo=null&page=1&pageSize=20
```

Here is the error:

```
{
    "errors": {
    "dateTo": [
        "The value 'null' is not valid."
    ],
    "dateFrom": [
        "The value 'null' is not valid."
    ]
    },
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|8c4093d7-485e79a6a805ceae."  
}
```

But when I leave it as blank as below, it will work. Can't we pass `null` instead of `blank space`?

```
http://localhost:5000/api/Inv/filter?dateFrom=&dateTo=&page=1&pageSize=20
```

Also, getting same error when we try to send them from UI as well.

Comment: Maybe the parser think `null` is not null. It's a string with value "null". just like "2021-07-13". And failed to parse it to `DateTime`.

Comment: I think omitting it is the intended way to do it. AYou can write your own value providers. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#additional-sources

Comment: don't now, how you build the query string, but if there is a type defined for your data, you could define a getter for the DateTo to something like 'return dateTo ?? string.Empty' (with dateTo as the backing field of the prop - no autoprops in this case )

Answer (score 5):

Just don't pass the parameter in the query string.

Instead of
`http://localhost:5000/api/Inv/filter?dateFrom=null&dateTo=null&page=1&pageSize=20`
try
`http://localhost:5000/api/Inv/filter?page=1&pageSize=20`

Comment: From frontend also, should we handle like this?

Comment: There's surely a way to write a custom parser and use it, so that `null` gets parsed as you want, but I think that just not passing the parameter is the easiest option here.